# Require minimum number of shares in order to proceed in web app

Tags: api, share, sharing, facebook-social-plugins

We are putting together a contest of sorts, and are planning on integrating Facebook sharing as a method of proceeding deeper within the website as a qualification for entry into the contest.

The concept as pitched by the client involves a typical share button with popup box, where the user picks who they wish to share with. However, they want to require a minimum of 12 shares.

Firstly:
"Is this even possible?"

Secondly:
How might we go about validating that a given user actually shared the required number of people, or that the shared at all?

I imagine there might be a way to redirect them to the landing page after the sharing procedure somehow. We're still trying to wrap our heads around this process and if it is even doable the way they want.

Comment: Facebook isn't going to let you do that, because that's tantamount to encouraging users to spam. I remember that American Express had a Wish-a-Day thingy for holiday season last year, which initially had a feature to give you points if you did a wall post promoting the promotion. They had to pull that a couple of days in (so that you could get the points whether you did the wall post or not).

Comment: Okay, thank you. That's some good advice. I appreciate you including an example that I can share with the client tomorrow. BTW...this wasn't my idea. Just the developer trying to figure it out  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Chris Jester-Young's response was probably sufficient. Doing this is a bad idea and we spoke to the client this morning and got part of the contest changed. Thanks for at least speaking up about it, as I wasn't sure if what we wanted was even doable the way we were thinking.